# Struggling to get scons to work with mingw on windows

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, scons

Trying to get a test case working so that I can compile C++ using scons.

However I am getting this error:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...

scons: warning: No version of Visual Studio compiler found - C/C++ compilers most likely not set correctly
File "C:\Python27\Scripts\scons.py", line 199, in <module>
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/g++.exe -o test.o -c test.cpp
scons: *** [test.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Here is my SConstruct at this time:

```
env = Environment(tools = ["mingw"],  TARGET_ARCH=['x86'])
env.Replace(CXX = 'C:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/g++.exe')
env.Program("main","test.cpp")
```

I am confused by the visual studio error, because I have specified that I want to use mingw.

Answer (score 0):

My problem in this case was caused by me using PowerShell for the first time. Which for some reason that I have not yet learned, does not provide popups of error messages. When I used cmd I saw that I had a path issue, and scons was otherwise working fine.

Comment: Correct, it's not an error but only a warning. If you'd want to get rid of it completely, you'd have to specify an empty `tools` variable for the DefaultEnvironment as well. The latter gets initialized automatically...